# how to use my_getch in c++?

Tags: c++, getch

I created a getch-liked function using windows.h-GetKeyState and it working well but when I do it in loops it get the same char lots of times. what sould I do?

I am using gcc 4.9.2 code blocks windows 10 .

my code is :

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

bool pressed(int key){return GetKeyState(key)&0x8000;}

int my_getch(){
while(true){
bool shift=pressed(VK_SHIFT);
for(char a='A'; a<='Z'; a++) if(pressed(a)) return shift||GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL)?a:a-'A'+'a';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_3)) return shift?'~':'`';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_4)) return shift?'{':'[';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_6)) return shift?'}':']';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_5)) return shift?'|':'\\';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_1)) return shift?':':';';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_7)) return shift?'"':'\'';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_COMMA)) return shift?'<':',';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_PERIOD)) return shift?'>':'.';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_2)) return shift?'?':'/';
if(pressed('1')) return shift?'!':'1';
if(pressed('2')) return shift?'@':'2';
if(pressed('3')) return shift?'#':'3';
if(pressed('4')) return shift?'$':'4';
if(pressed('5')) return shift?'%':'5';
if(pressed('6')) return shift?'^':'6';
if(pressed('7')) return shift?'&':'7';
if(pressed('8')) return shift?'*':'8';
if(pressed('9')) return shift?'(':'9';
if(pressed('0')) return shift?')':'0';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_MINUS)) return shift?'_':'-';
if(pressed(VK_OEM_PLUS)) return shift?'+':'=';
if(pressed('\b')) return '\b';
if(pressed(VK_DIVIDE)) return '/';
if(pressed(VK_MULTIPLY)) return '*';
if(pressed(VK_ADD)) return '+';
if(pressed(VK_SUBTRACT)) return '-';
if(pressed('\t')) return '\t';
if(pressed(' ')) return ' ';
for(int i=VK_NUMPAD0; i<=VK_NUMPAD9; i++) if(pressed(i))  return i-VK_NUMPAD0+'0';
if(pressed(VK_DECIMAL)) return '.';
if(pressed('\r')) return '\n';
}
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, char*, int){
while(true) std::cout<<my_getch()<<'\r';
return 0;}
```

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: I don't know what the situation is here with console apps and message loops, but the documentation is pretty clear that `GetKeyState` is not real-time. I could certainly see a hot loop preventing the state from being updated.

Comment: A quick look at the documentation shows you should probably be using [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs for [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads key messages from its message queue. The status does not reflect the interrupt-level state associated with the hardware. Use the GetAsyncKeyState function to retrieve that information.

Which suggests that you should be using [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) instead. From the docs:

> Determines whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called, and whether the key was pressed after a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

Comment: @RoyAviDan What does that mean? What happened?

Comment: the same problem

Comment: I prabobly didn't understand how to use it